# Windows 7 ISO download from Digital River

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I'm having troubles installing Windows 7 on an older laptop (certified for W7). It takes forever to install all updates. I started two days ago with updating. The installation DVD is quite old, before SP1. I installed SP1, rebooted maybe seven times since then, have no idea how many times to go.

I've found [ISO images of Windows 7](http://www.techverse.net/download-windows-7-iso-x86-x64-microsofts-official-servers/) on Digital River, the official MS download site. When I use these, do they have the latest updates? So would it be a good idea to start over with one of those images?

Comment: Microsoft has not released a new .ISO since Service Pack 1 was released.  You can add those updates yourself to the .ISO and update the .ISO yourself but you still have to download the updates.

Comment: Just found http://www.wsusoffline.net/docs/, which downloads all updates and has an installer included. I'm going to try that!

Comment: There is something called Baseline windows which was made to make it easy to add updates to windows isos. They created a base iso and released updates seperately, and you can download the updates and add those to that iso and make a new iso which has that updates inside it without the trouble of downloading the whole windows files. But! unfortunately they are gone. I dont know why but they have stopped the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would be better off using those. You see where it says SP1, that stands for service pack one meaning it's preloaded into the ISO image. You can use a program called [UNetbootin] (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for flash drives. After the install is complete i suggest getting all your drivers installed, if you don't have them do a Google search, for example: HP Pavilion dv7-3065dx drivers. For the updates never do more than 50 at a time or it may fail to configure changes so take your time and find a Ethernet cable to speed up the downloads. Also since these ISO images have SP1 you do not need to download those updates.